# Object appears mottled in views and renders

Tags: rendering, mesh

Anyone know why my object appears corrupted and spottled after decimate? I tried flipping normals, deleting uv's and adding a material, to no avail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to attached the said model so that someone can look into it as there could be more than meet the eyes. I suggest using this link to attach the model. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. It sure looks to me that the normals on the said model has been messed up after the decimate operation. Seen a topic somewhere in stack exchange. Couldn't find it at the moment.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2958" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2958/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup found your problem it's indeed an issue with your Normal data on the model.

These are the steps

1. Goto Properies panel "Data" tab.
2. Goto "Geometry Data" Header
3. Select "Clear Custom Split normal Data"

That's all to it. There is a history to this thing, can't remember them at the moment may add to the answer later.

[image]

Comment: Aha! Thanks very much. Never would have guessed that. I had "custom split normals data," eh? I have to look that one up, no idea what it is. But thank you.